# My JavaScript for hiding/showing HTML is removing CSS for the respective elements it changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bit of code that hides or shows an HTML element when I click a button:

```js
function showMonth() {
    var x = document.getElementById("calendarDiv");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("timelineDiv").style.display = "none";
    } 
}

function showWeek() {
    var x = document.getElementById("timelineDiv");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("calendarDiv").style.display = "none";
    } 
}
```

However, when press my showWeek button after pressing the showMonth button, the html for my week is all very different from how it was before I pressed any button. I think it might be removing/ignoring the CSS that it was seeing before. Any  ideas/opinions/help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the HTML/CSS, or even better, create a jsfiddle reproducing the problem ?

Comment: What was style.display before? Are you sure it was inline-block? Inspect it and set it to the same value. Then it should work.

Comment: Please create a code snippet and add the necessary HTML/CSS for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies, ill try what XraySensei said first then make a jsfiddle

Comment: I'd suggest putting it in a (native) code snippet, so that answers on this platform don't require third-party services. You could simply create one in your answer. @Bubinga

Comment: Thanks a bunch to all of you but especially XraySensei, what you suggested worked! It turned out it was "inline-flex" not "inline-block". :) I'll be sure to remember that for next time @Daan, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, if you can use jQuery in your code.

```
CSS:
.Hide {
    Display: none !important;
}

Javascript:
function showMonth() {
    var x = document.getElementById("calendarDiv");
    if ($('#calendarDiv').hasClass("Hide")) {
        $('#calendarDiv').removeClass("Hide");
        $('#timelineDiv').addClass("Hide");
    } 
}

function showWeek() {
    var x = document.getElementById("timelineDiv");
    if ($('#timelineDiv').hasClass("Hide")) {
        $('#timelineDiv').removeClass("Hide");
        $('#calendarDiv').addClass("Hide");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Show hide element like this. you sure  x.style.display = "inline-block" not 
 x.style.display = "block"

```
function showMonth() {
            var x = document.getElementById("calendarDiv");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";    
            } 
        else{
         x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function showWeek() {
        var x = document.getElementById("timelineDiv");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "inline-block";
        } 
      else{
         x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The extra code there was to remove a calendar and swap it out with the week format. I solved it by changing "inline block" to "inline-flex"